# Disadvantage of the strategy pattern and how to overcome it

Tags: design, design-patterns, strategy, strategy-pattern

An often quoted disadvantage of the strategy pattern is:

> The application must be aware of all the strategies to select the
> right one for the right situation

Why is this a disadvantage and what can be done to overcome it?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Translation of gnat's comment: can you please provide a reference (or two) for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue here.  We could say that the disadvantage of if statements is that the application needs to know all the conditions to check.  In addition, this seems to be [anthropomorphizing](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/264) computers which can harm understanding.

Comment: I think OP refers to several webpages such as [this](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/patterns/article.php/c845/Applying-Strategy-Pattern-in-C-Applications.htm), [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/889/Applying-Strategy-Pattern-in-C-Applications) or [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/design-patterns-strategy-pattern-in-dart-7c833812d58d) and 55 others, which all provide a very similar list of pros and cons.

Comment: The quoted disadvantage comes from a purely theoretical background. In reality, unless you deal with some very complex issues like robotics, nuclear power or some sort of starship, you should know all the possible algorithms in advance anyways(or you should know them very well if the problem domain was well documented and researched beforehand), regardless of what pattern you will be using, thus this disadvantage is moot.

Answer (score 12):

This quote is surprising and misleading. **Design patterns are not chosen in a catalogue** by comparing pros and cons!  Patterns are chosen because they address a very specific problem that you are facing. If it doesn't suit the need, just don't take it.

The **intent** of the strategy pattern is:

> Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable.  Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently of the client.

If you have a problem like that, just use the pattern.  Whether the application has to know which strategy to use and how to chose it is secondary. It's eventually a **consequence**, but certainly not a disadvantage.

Lastly, this quote is **not fully true** either:  you could encapsulate the strategy and package it in a dynamic library loaded at run time and instantiated through a factory function with a fixed name.  Your application may then just rely on the DLL, knowing just the strategy's interface without knowing what exact strategy implementation it is.  That's the power of decoupling that the strategy pattern offers.

*Post Scriptum: The "often quoted disadvantage" appears with an exact match in 58 web pages according to google.  Several are from the same author who cross-posted it, and the oldest dating back to 1999.  I'm not sure that such a small cluster qualifies for "often quoted"*

Answer (score 2):

[@Christoph's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/420975) is perfectly correct, but I am not sure if it really is what you want to know. Hence, let me try to approach this from a slightly different angle.

IMHO the author of that quote simply chose a bad title for the section. Instead of

> "Drawbacks in using Strategy Pattern"

a better title could have been something like

> "Conditions under which the Strategy Pattern is applicable"

and one of that conditions is *"an application is aware of all the strategies to select the right one for the right situation"*. I hope, this sentence now becomes more sensible.

So let us assume the title would have been like that. Let us further assume to be in a situation where an application requires **configurable behaviour**, where using the Strategy might be the first idea for solving it.

This makes your original question transform to

**In what situations would an application not be aware of all the strategies to select from?**

The answer which comes immediately into my mind here is,

- when picking from different predefined Strategy objects is simply not flexible enough to fulfil the configuration requirements.

**And how can an application provide configurable behaviour without using the Strategy Pattern, in a more flexible manner?** Well, it could

- provide some complex set options and parameters, ideally orthogonal options, maybe with placeholder functionality or templates
- provide its own scripting language or DSL for allowing users of the application to provide new behaviour or algorithms
- provide some plugin mechanism (which, to be fair, is often implemented using the Strategy Pattern, but with user-provided Strategy objects, not with the ones provided by the application)
- a mixture of those.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy pattern requires the *caller* to specify the strategy in order to execute it. The reason this is a disadvantage is that it couples the caller's logic to the strategy's.

An alternative would be to use the chain of responsibility + strategy pattern. Under this approach, more than one "strategy" is assigned, and each strategy gets to decide if it can do the work. Thus the logic to invoke the strategy is contained in the strategy itself.

For example

```
interface IHandler
{
    bool CanHandle(object thing);
    void Handle(object thing);
}

class FooHandler : IHandler
{
    public bool CanHandle(object thing) => thing is Foo;

    void Handle(object thing)
    {
        //Do something with the Foo
    }
}

class BarHandler : IHandler
{
    public bool CanHandle(object thing) => thing is Bar;

    void Handle(object thing)
    {
        //Do something with the Bar
    }
}


//Initialization
var handlers = new IHandler[] 
{
    new FooHandler(),
    new BarHandler()
};

//Main program
void HandleSomething(object input)
{
    foreach (var handler in handlers)
    {
        if (handler.CanHandle(input)) handler.Handle(input);
    }
}
```

This way, the main program doesn't need to know what all the "strategies" are or when they need to be used.

Comment: This is great, but this requires updating the `handlers` each time you add a new class that implements `IHandler`. Is there a way so that you wouldn't need to modify other parts of the code when you add a new strategy implementation?

Comment: @MehdiCharife The handlers could register themselves, or you could populate the list by using Reflection to find all classes that implement `IHandler`. But it seems to me that the list of handlers is important enough where you might want to declare it explicitly somewhere, either in code (as I have) or via configuration.

Comment: "The strategy pattern requires the caller to specify the strategy in order to execute it." No, it doesn't. The strategy can be changed by any sorts of other forces that do not rely on the caller.

Answer (score -1):

Some long posts here, but it comes down to the following

Disadvantage: Because all behavior classes must be known, it is not easily extensible.

Mitigation; Use in conjunction with an Abstract Factory pattern.  Then you can inject the factory you need.

Answer (score -1):

Without the context the disadvantage is quoted from it can be fantasised about it endlessly. An attempt to create a context for disadvantages close to reality might be that strategy design pattern is an impediment when it's about self evolving software, since foreseeing all the possibilities at development phase is utopic. Even with a context similar with the afore imagined one the quoted statement holds true for some cases only. The often used implementation example for strategy design pattern of mathematical operations could be a good depict. Imagine there is implemented a strategy just for addition operation. Implement the addition strategy using recurrence with a parameter for repetitions and there is no need to know about multiplication.

So the answer to the question "why is this a disadvantage" is the question "in what context?" and the answer to the question "what can be done about it?" is "imagine a broader context while development phase".

Update to harmonise with the comments

It might have a flavour of exaggeration yet by my experience reading code is the single source of learning the proper way to code so I imagined, that is the first step towards envisioned, this is a digression, the utility to temporise the clicks/taps on a button in a UI to depict a way around the boundaries set at the analysis phase. The following code snippet implements strategy design pattern that supports running itself thus going around the context of knowing all the possibilities of usage while the development phase (there are comments in the code to mark the strategy implementations).

```
var thresholder = (function() {
    
    return { supply : (betweenShifts) => {
        
        return {
            
            millis : () => { return {
            
                or : (alternativeFunction) => {
                    
                    var millisSinceShift = Date.now();

                    // strategy design pattern implementation
                    return (shiftFunction) => {
                        
                        if ( Date.now() - millisSinceShift > betweenShifts ) {
                            millisSinceShift = Date.now();
                            shiftFunction();
                            return;
                        }
                        millisSinceShift = Date.now();
                        setTimeout( () => { alternativeFunction(); }, 1);
                    };
                    
                }
            } }
            , taps : () => {
                    
                    return { inMillis : (millisBetweenTaps) => {
                        
                        return { or : (alternativeFunction) => {
                            
                            var counter = (function(from) {
                                var tapCounter = from;
                                
                                return { incremented : () => { return ++tapCounter; } 
                                       , decremented : () => { return --tapCounter; }
                                       , counted : () => { return tapCounter; }
                                       , reset : () => { tapCounter = from; }
                                       };
                            })(1);
                            var previousShiftMillis = Date.now();
                            
                            // strategy design pattern implementation
                            return (shiftFunction) => {
                                    if ( Date.now() - previousShiftMillis >= millisBetweenTaps ) { 
                                        previousShiftMillis = Date.now();
                                        counter.reset();
                                    }
                                    
                                    if ( counter.counted() > betweenShifts ) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    
                                    if ( counter.incremented() == betweenShifts ) {
                                        setTimeout( () => { alternativeFunction(); }, 1);
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    shiftFunction();
                            };
                        } };
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    } };
} )();
```

Strategy instances:

```
var secondsBetweenShifts = 2;
var millisBetweenShifts = secondsBetweenShifts * 1000;
var alternative = () => { /* on click / on tap alternative code */ };
var tapper = thresholder.supply(3).taps().inMillis(millisBetweenShifts)
                        .or( alternative );
var shift = thresholder.supply(millisBetweenShifts).millis()
                       .or( alternative );
```

Usage of strategy running itself:

```
tapper( () => { shift( () => { /* on click / on tap function to call */ } ); } );
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/253489)